# wrapping C or C++ library what are the advantages and disavantages

Tags: c++, c, binding, shared-libraries, wrapper

I'm writing a few libraries and I want them to be available in C and C++, then wrap them with swig to make them available for Ruby, Python, Java, Lisp, ...

What are the advantages and disadvantages to writing a library in C and then wrapping the library in C++ instead of writing it in C++ and then wrapping it in C?

The only things I can think of would be if the library is written in C++ then C programs might need a C++ compiler to be compiled, though maybe I'm not right on that

There might also be some features or things that don't wrap.

I'm mainly asking for experience, to know what I may run into while doing this project.

Comment: C++ doesn't have a stable abi and few languages can link to it, different versions of the same compiler may not even be able to link. C has a stable abi and nearly every language has a C ffi.

Comment: @sjdowling, that's a good point there, yet swig can supposedly wrap C++ for all languages, though I'm not sure how that works

Comment: @sjdowling: On some platforms, it has a stable ABI. At least for most things.

Comment: I will vote for C as well, for the same reason mentioned above, stable abi. When you need to upgrade to a new version, you will know the pain with c++.

Comment: It also depends on how your library is organized. If it (meaning its user interface) relies heavily on templates, you will have to instantiate all your templates manually to get them wrapped, which might or might not be practical for your application. Other than that, "stable ABI" is of course an argument. But SWIG is pretty good at wrapping C++ code. As far as I understand, the additional interface library it creates (which is then accessed from Python, etc.) exports a C ABI, so the difficulties of the C++ API don't become visible to the target language.

Comment: @Oguk that's a pretty good explanation. wrapping templates sounds pretty terrible. I'm designing this library still, and I've got very little implemented, so it would not matter yet if I have to change the design.

Comment: I must admit that my experience is limited to wrapping C/C++ for Python (not for any other of the languages you mentioned). Limiting yourself to C is certainly a safe option, but SWIG has all the nice wrappers for STL containers and provides means to easily map the operators in your custom classes to equivalent structures in Python, so, if object orientation is an important concept for your library, wrapping C++ in the first place is probably less messy than limiting yourself to C and then "rebuilding" nice structures in the target language.

Comment: Another thought: Since you know you're going to wrap this library, it should be relatively easy to check you're staying within the range of SWIG's capabilities while you are writing the code. It probably doesn't impose a lot of limits (see [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Introduction_nn10)), but in that way you can minimize the need for manual workarounds. Things usually get a lot messier when you decide to wrap a library that was developed over the course of several years without that idea in mind.

Comment: @Oguk thanks for the information. I'll use it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Write in C, wrap in C++:

#### Advantages

- If your C code is Object Oriented in some way, or simply doesn't do any macro and similar tricks, making a C++ wrapper should be easy
- Actually, you may use SWIG or similar tool to make the C++ wrapper and then use the same artefacts (like SWIG interface file) to make other (Ruby, Python...) wrappers
- If you have an idea about the languages you want to interface (say, Ruby and Python, but not Lisp or others) then you may write the C++ wrapper in a way that would make it easier to write wrappers for those languages (even without SWIG)

#### Disadvantages

- One may be caught in making a C++ wrapper which is too C++-ish (with too many templates, for example) which may be very hard to wrap in another language
- There are but a few languages that support interfacing C++ directly, especially whole C++. So, you are pretty much required to write a wrapper for other languages.

### Write in C++, wrap in C:

#### Advantages

- C is an easier language to interface with, because it is a simpler language and most environments/OSes are written in C.
- Actually, if you follow some conventions ("ABI"), most languages provide a way to call into C DLL/.so without any wrapper at all. It is ugly, for the most part, but serves well for simpler interfaces, prototypes, etc.

#### Disadvatages

- Interfacing to C is not as "easy as pie", so may get into trouble if you're not careful. For example, on Windows, to export a function from a DLL you have to mark it "exported", which only has a "de facto" standard way of doing. There are also struct alignment, enum size(s) and other issues.
- Interfacing C++ from C is harder than vice versa. You have to make sure your exceptions don't propagate from C++, properly "translate" C++ templates (remember that std::string is a template), various inheritance idioms (interfaces, mix-ins, "regular" multiple inheritance...) in the interface...

### My recommendation

I've done both, and my experience suggests that you should write the module in the language that better suits you for the task at hand. When you're done, interface to the other and then wrap to all the rest. Actually, nobody is preventing you from wrapping the C interface from one language (say, Ruby) and c++ from another (say, Python - using Cython).

Interfacing between C and C++ is way easier than interfacing any of them with (almost all) other languages, so should not be a very significant influence in deciding the primary development language.

Comment: This is a very good answer though one thing seems a bit off to me
under the advantages for "Write in C++, wrap in C" you listed that C was easier then talked about the C ABI. Should that not have been advantages for C++?

Comment: I meant that this is an advantage for using C as the interface language (thus C++ being the implementation language).